# How to get System date in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to get system date in pyspark. 
I have tried some code but it is giving me yesterday date.
Can you help me to solve this?

code:

```
spark.sql("SELECT ID AS GRP_ID, DEV_NM AS GRP_NM, NAME, TYPE, from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), 'EST5EDT') AS IM_INSERT_DT  FROM vw_grp").show(2)
```

output:

```
+------------------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------+
|            GRP_ID|         GRP_NM|        NAME|     TYPE|        IM_INSERT_DT|
+------------------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------+
|00G0B000002cpcjUAA|   DM_ONC_Users|DM_ONC_Users|  Regular|2020-01-16 23:58:...|
|00G0B000002cpoQUAQ|X105_30_5000035|        null|Territory|2020-01-16 23:58:...|
+------------------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------+
```

I want today's date : 2020-01-17 15:34:15

Comment: Just filter using your datetime column?

Comment: @JasonChia how sir?

Comment: `from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), 'EST5EDT')` Assumes given timestamp `(current_timestamp())` is UTC and converts to given timezone , here `EST5EDT` (Eastern Standard Time ==  UTC - {5:00 or 4:00}). Are you sure your time is UTC?

Comment: My bad misunderstood you, seems you want to show your DF with the current timestamp. You should double check your utc conversion.

Comment: Here the comand `from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), 'EST5EDT')` is working fine, it just returned "2020-01-17T08:44:21.329+0000". Maybe your system is set with the wrong time.